# Accessing a temporary table multiple times in MySql

Tags: mysql, temp-tables

I have tried to use a temporary table as an intermediate result holder for a SELECT statement. The problem is though that I can't access the temp table multiple times in other queries statement which I hoped would be possible i.e. makes the temp table useless.

Is there an alternative to temporary tables in MySql that allows me to extract my SQL statement.

I can't use store procedures (can't access them from the web-framework version used in the company) and I don't want to use a cursor.

Edit:

Well my code looks somewhat like this:

Temp table creation:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE dates_with_entries (
  seq  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  datum VARCHAR(32)
);

INSERT INTO dates_with_entries (datum) SELECT datum AS Datum from project_times
    WHERE user_id = 20 GROUP BY datum ORDER BY datum desc LIMIT 13;
```

Then the code where I use my temp table looks somewhat like this (I simpled it down to the problem I have..)

```
SELECT 
...
FROM (SELECT entrie_date AS datum FROM dates_with_entries ) AS sub_result
INNER JOIN project_times
    ON sub_result.datum = project_times.datum AND project_times.user_id = 20
LEFT JOIN works AS w ON project_times.work_id = w.id
LEFT JOIN sub_projects AS sp ON sp.id = w.sub_project_id
LEFT JOIN projects AS p ON p.id = sp.project_id
GROUP BY datum
UNION(
    SELECT
      ..
  FROM (SELECT entrie_date AS datum FROM dates_with_entries ) AS sub_result
  INNER JOIN project_times AS pt ON pt.datum = sub_result.datum
  INNER JOIN works AS w on w.id = pt.work_id
  INNER JOIN sub_projects AS sp on w.sub_project_id = sp.id
  INNER JOIN projects AS p ON sp.project_id = p.id
  WHERE pt.user_id = 20
);
```

The numbers will be later on replaced by ruby, this is only for testing the SQL statement.

Comment: Show some sample SQL for how you create and use the temporary table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way around this is to simply create a "real" table, rather than a temporary table.

The advantages that temporary tables offer:

1. **Namespacing**. You can create multiple
   temporary tables with the same name
   in separate sessions.
2. **Automatic cleanup**. You don't need explicitly drop the table when you're done with
   it. It goes away when you end your session

If #1 is crucial for you, then you probably need to stick with temporary tables. Otherwise, if only one instance of this program runs at a time, or if you create the table name dynamically to make it unique, I recommend that you choose an appropriately unique name for this table and create it as a "real" table, then drop it when you're done.

Comment: Ok so the only way to achieve my goal is using a hack by defining a real table.. Well I guess I will have to go with that idea if I don't want any code duplication..

Comment: If you already know what the query is going to look like, create a second temporary table with identical schema to the first temporary table, then do a `INSERT INTO dates_with_entries2 SELECT * FROM dates_with_entires`, and finally, in your ultimate query, refer to the first temporary table in one spot, and the second temporary table in the other.

Answer (score 2):

Known bug (feature) - read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/temporary-table-problems.html

Here's how i work around the problem...

```
drop table if exists employees;
create table employees
(
emp_id smallint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
name varchar(255) not null,
boss_id smallint unsigned null,
key (boss_id)
)
engine = innodb;

insert into employees (name, boss_id) values
('f00',null), 
  ('ali later',1), 
  ('megan fox',1), 
      ('jessica alba',3), 
      ('eva longoria',3), 
         ('keira knightley',5), 
            ('liv tyler',6), 
            ('sophie marceau',6);


drop procedure if exists employees_hier;

delimiter #

create procedure employees_hier
(
in p_emp_id smallint unsigned
)
begin

declare v_done tinyint unsigned default(0);
declare v_dpth smallint unsigned default(0);

create temporary table hier(
 boss_id smallint unsigned, 
 emp_id smallint unsigned, 
 depth smallint unsigned
)engine = memory;

insert into hier select boss_id, emp_id, v_dpth from employees where emp_id = p_emp_id;

/* http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/temporary-table-problems.html */

create temporary table emps engine=memory select * from hier;

while not v_done do

    if exists( select 1 from employees e inner join hier on e.boss_id = hier.emp_id and hier.depth = v_dpth) then

        insert into hier select e.boss_id, e.emp_id, v_dpth + 1 
            from employees e inner join emps on e.boss_id = emps.emp_id and emps.depth = v_dpth;

        set v_dpth = v_dpth + 1;            

        truncate table emps;
        insert into emps select * from hier where depth = v_dpth;

    else
        set v_done = 1;
    end if;

end while;

select 
 e.emp_id,
 e.name as emp_name,
 p.emp_id as boss_emp_id,
 p.name as boss_name,
 hier.depth
from 
 hier
inner join employees e on hier.emp_id = e.emp_id
left outer join employees p on hier.boss_id = p.emp_id;

drop temporary table if exists hier;
drop temporary table if exists emps;

end #

delimiter ;

-- call this sproc from your php

call employees_hier(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

For this problem, where the temporary table is only to be read, I create a second temporary table as a copy of the first then use this in the query:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t2 as (SELECT * FROM dates_with_entries);
```

Then

```
SELECT 
...
FROM (SELECT entrie_date AS datum FROM dates_with_entries ) AS sub_result
INNER JOIN project_times
    ON sub_result.datum = project_times.datum AND project_times.user_id = 20
LEFT JOIN works AS w ON project_times.work_id = w.id
LEFT JOIN sub_projects AS sp ON sp.id = w.sub_project_id
LEFT JOIN projects AS p ON p.id = sp.project_id
GROUP BY datum
UNION(
    SELECT
      ..
  FROM (SELECT entrie_date AS datum FROM t2) AS sub_result
  INNER JOIN project_times AS pt ON pt.datum = sub_result.datum
  INNER JOIN works AS w on w.id = pt.work_id
  INNER JOIN sub_projects AS sp on w.sub_project_id = sp.id
  INNER JOIN projects AS p ON sp.project_id = p.id
  WHERE pt.user_id = 20
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried "WITH" for this problem but apparently it is not supported by MySQL on my server yet. I came across this solution that seems like working. It uses "CREATE VIEW" to replicate "WITH" in MySQL

http://guilhembichot.blogspot.com/2013/11/with-recursive-and-mysql.html

Comment: When answering with a link, please copy relevant portions of code into your answer (if permitted by license at the link) - so your answer is still useful even if the link goes dead. NOTE: As you mention, the link shows using "CREATE VIEW", which is a non-temporary definition, though it has the benefit of being populated with current data per query.