# How can I refer to a TEMPORARY table more than once in the same query?

Tags: mysql, union, temp-tables

the MySQL docs say: "You cannot refer to a TEMPORARY table more than once in the same query."

I know this has been asked before. But I can't find a specific solution for the following.

I'm doing a preselection into a temporary table

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE preselection AS SELECT ...;
```

now I wanna do some (around 20 or even 30) unions

```
(SELECT FROM preselection ...)
UNION
(SELECT FROM preselection ...)
UNION
......
UNION
(SELECT FROM preselection ...)
```

I could make 20 or 30 copies of preselection and do each select on each table but if I understand it right this is the same as invoke the preselection-query above in every SELECT inside the UNION chain as a subquery.

Is there a way to work around this issue?

Greetings,

chris

Full query:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE preselection AS
(
SELECT id, title, chapter, date2, date, snid, max(score) FROM `movies`

WHERE 
(
cluster is not NULL
) 
AND 
(
`date` <= '2012-02-20 05:20:00'
AND `date` > '2012-02-19 17:20:00' 
AND (TIMEDIFF(date, date2) < '12:00:00')
)
GROUP BY cluster
)
UNION
(
SELECT id, title, chapter, date2, date, snid, score FROM `movies`
WHERE cluster IS NULL
AND
(
`date` <= '2012-02-20 05:20:00' AND `date` > '2012-02-19 17:20:00' AND (TIMEDIFF(date, date2) < '12:00:00')
)
);

(SELECT * FROM preselection WHERE snid=1 AND chapter LIKE '#A_OT%'
 DESC LIMIT 4)
UNION
 … 
UNION 
(SELECT * FROM preselection WHERE snid=19 AND chapter LIKE '#A_OT%' 
 LIMIT 4)
UNION
 ... for each chapter from A to J and every snid from 1 to 19 ...
UNION
(SELECT * FROM preselection WHERE snid=1 AND chapter LIKE '#J_OT%'
 LIMIT 4)
UNION
 … 
UNION 
(SELECT * FROM preselection WHERE snid=19 AND chapter LIKE '#J_OT%' 
LIMIT 4)

ORDER BY `score` DESC, `date`;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing a temporary table multiple times in MySql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078873/accessing-a-temporary-table-multiple-times-in-mysql)

Comment: Can you show the full, real query? It might help us come up with ideas for a workaround that doesn't require adding the temp table multiple times.

Comment: Maybe it's a good idea. Here its my full query, I really have no idea how to do it in a different way.

(ADDED TO THE POST)

Comment: I often run into this same issue and although i haven't tried I've wondered if a table variable will give this functionality. Its just something else you can try.

Answer (score 4):

I think the error message is clear: you can't do that with a single temporary table. Does creating a view of the data, instead of a temporary tables, do the trick?

[Views in mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-view.html)

Comment: I do this "trick" all the time for many different problems.  It's a good habit to get used to.

Comment: @Mosty, Problem with views is that they are global. There doesn't seem to be any way to create session-local "temporary views". This will cause problems when there are multiple simultaneous queries.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can be frustrating. The solutions I typically use involve avoiding the temporary table with a more complex query or using more temporary tables.

A simple copy (but like you mentioned this is no use to you)

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE preselectionCopy AS
SELECT * FROM preselection;
```

Or a temporary table to hold your results

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE result (
    id INT NULL,
    title VARCHAR(256) NULL
    ...
    );
```

...which can be as simple as

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE result AS
SELECT * FROM preselection WHERE snid=1 AND chapter LIKE '#A_OT%' 
LIMIT 4;

INSERT INTO result
SELECT * FROM preselection WHERE snid=19 AND chapter LIKE '#A_OT%' 
 LIMIT 4;

...

SELECT * FROM result 
ORDER BY `score` DESC, `date`;
```