# Select count on different columns of same temporary table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Suppose I have a table (in MySQL) like:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY table IF NOT EXISTS tbl  
(   
    REF_REQ_ID int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    FunctionalArea varchar(200),
    Industry varchar(200)
);

INSERT INTO tbl
SELECT 1, 'IT Jobs', 'IT related Jobs' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'HR Jobs', NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, NULL, 'HR related Jobs' UNION ALL
SELECT 4, NULL, 'IT related Jobs' UNION ALL
SELECT 5, NULL, NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'IT Jobs', 'IT related Jobs' UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 'HR Jobs', NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 8, NULL, 'HR related Jobs' UNION ALL
SELECT 9, 'HR Jobs', NULL;
```

I would like to join and combine two columns in single columns(`distinct` values) and sorted on `NoOfJobs`, how can I achieve that?

**Expected Result**

```
JobTitle         NoOfJobs
HR Jobs           3
IT related Jobs   3
HR related Jobs   2
IT Jobs           2
```

Please comment if you have any query or question content is not appropriate.

Datebase is MySQL, I know how I could achieve this in SQL Server.

Just run this query(For MS SQL Server):

```
DECLARE  @tbl  table
(   
    REF_REQ_ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
    FunctionalArea varchar(200),
    Industry varchar(200)
)

INSERT INTO @tbl
SELECT 'IT Jobs', 'IT related Jobs' UNION ALL
SELECT 'HR Jobs', NULL UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, 'HR related Jobs' UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, 'IT related Jobs' UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 'IT Jobs', 'IT related Jobs' UNION ALL
SELECT 'HR Jobs', NULL UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, 'HR related Jobs' UNION ALL
SELECT 'HR Jobs', NULL

SELECT 
    JobTitle As JobTitle,
    COUNT(REF_REQ_ID) As NoOfJobs
FROM    
    (SELECT 
        FunctionalArea As JobTitle,
        REF_REQ_ID
    FROM @tbl
    UNION 
    SELECT 
        Industry As JobTitle,
        REF_REQ_ID
    FROM @tbl)t
WHERE JobTitle IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY JobTitle
ORDER BY NoOfJobs desc
```

It would give me the result what I expected, but unfortunately MySQL doesn't support `UNION` on same table (temporary).

**MySQL readers**: How I can achieve the expected result?

**SQL Server readers**: Alternative way to do the same?

Comment: DO you really need to create temporary table? If that is not the case, you should convert your table to a normal table, and then `UNION ALL` will work. `UNION ALL` operation cannot work on temporary tables in MySQL by design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting answer, its give me expected result, and thanks a lot to all.

I have added one more **temporary table** to it(not **real table**)

```
CREATE TEMPORARY table IF NOT EXISTS tbl  
(   
    REF_REQ_ID int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    FunctionalArea varchar(200),
    Industry varchar(200)
);

TRUNCATE TABLE tbl;

INSERT INTO tbl
SELECT 1, 'IT Jobs', 'IT related Jobs' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'HR Jobs', NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, NULL, 'HR related Jobs' UNION ALL
SELECT 4, NULL, 'IT related Jobs' UNION ALL
SELECT 5, NULL, NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'IT Jobs', 'IT related Jobs' UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 'HR Jobs', NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 8, NULL, 'HR related Jobs' UNION ALL
SELECT 9, 'HR Jobs', NULL;

CREATE TEMPORARY table IF NOT EXISTS tbl_industry
(   
    REF_REQ_ID int,
    Industry varchar(200)
);

TRUNCATE TABLE tbl_industry;

INSERT INTO tbl_industry
SELECT 
    REF_REQ_ID,
    Industry 
FROM tbl
WHERE Industry IS NOT NULL;


SELECT 
    JobTitle As JobTitle,
    COUNT(REF_REQ_ID) As NoOfJobs
FROM    
    (SELECT 
        FunctionalArea As JobTitle,
        REF_REQ_ID
    FROM tbl
    UNION 
    SELECT 
        Industry As JobTitle,
        REF_REQ_ID
    FROM tbl_industry)t
WHERE JobTitle IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY JobTitle
ORDER BY NoOfJobs desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (
select FunctionalArea as JobTitle,count(1) as NoOfJobs
from tbl
where FunctionalArea IS NOT NULL
group by FunctionalArea
UNION ALL
select Industry as JobTitle,count(1)as NoOfJobs
from tbl
where Industry IS NOT NULL
group by Industry) t
order by t.NoOfJobs desc
```

Results

```
JobTitle         NoOfJobs
HR Jobs           3
IT related Jobs   3
HR related Jobs   2
IT Jobs           2
```

[Demo is Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/8156f/7)

Note: I've used Different Table name in Demo sqlfiddle.

Comment: However, this query doesn't work when applied to a temporary table.  You can see the error in SqlFiddle by changing to a temporary table and moving the select statement to the "Build Schema" side.

Comment: This solution does not work for temporary table, which OP has specified.

Comment: @dan1111 I'm SQL server Guy and I Don't have idea on MySQL' Temporary tables, I did with Real Tables. Any idea how to get it work?

Comment: @ViswanathanIyer we could find an alternate way to do the same in SQL Server without `UNION ALL`

Comment: Now I got know the team in MySQL You can't refer Temporary table Twice http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/temporary-table-problems.html

Comment: again thanks a lot........ you guys are genius, just posting my answer and then we discuss how we could go forward and make that better

Comment: @vikas Post your answer and close the discussion. :)

Comment: @ViswanathanIyer I am satisfied with my answer, but can we do it without one more temporary table

Comment: @vikas as per MySQL documentation  dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/temporary-table-problems.html We can't, but there should be alternate solution on internet.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to create a real table instead of a temporary table.

As long as you remember to delete the table when you are done, and as long as the table name doesn't clash with other table names, then it won't make any difference.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078873/accessing-a-temporary-table-multiple-times-in-mysql) has a nice discussion of that, and it also shows another workaround (though the other workaround is a lot messier than just using a real table, in my opinion).

**Update:** another possibility would be to re-design so that the union happens before the temporary table: the temporary table could be filled with the results of the union operation.  Whether that makes sense would depend on the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot refer to a TEMPORARY table more than once in the same query. For example, the following does not work:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM temp_table, temp_table AS t2;
ERROR 1137: Can't reopen table: 'temp_table'
```

[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/temporary-table-problems.html)

@dan1111 solution looks good.